# Inserting a pdf file to SQL table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a pdf file into a sql table (varbinary column)

```
create table pdfTest(pdfData varbinary(max))
declare @filePath varchar(100)
set @filePath = 'c:\pdfSample.pdf'
INSERT INTO pdfTest (pdfData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @filePath, SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

However this gives an error

```
 Incorrect syntax near '@filePath'.
```

None of the following assignment works

```
 set @filePath = 'c:'\pdfSample.pdf'
 set @filePath = 'c:\\pdfSample.pdf'
```

But the following syntax works

```
 INSERT INTO pdfTest (pdfData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\pdfSample.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

Just wondering how @filePath can be used in the insert statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here the variable name is not getting resolved. Try using the variable name in dynamic sql.

```
 Declare @sql varchar(max)
 Set @sql='INSERT INTO pdfTest (pdfData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'+ @filePath+', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB'
 exec @sql
```

Comment: This gives error: Could not find stored procedure 'INSERT INTO pdfTest (pdfData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULKc:\pdfSample.pdf, SINGLE_BLOB) AS VARBINARY'.   it's removing the single quotes from the filePath

Comment: @bluepiranha, just change `exec @sql` to `exec(@sql)`

Comment: @bluepiranha, and `OPENROWSET(BULK'+ @filePath+', SINGLE_BLOB)` to `OPENROWSET(BULK'''+ @filePath+''', SINGLE_BLOB)`

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
 Set @sql='INSERT INTO pdfTest (pdfData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ @filePath+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB'
 exec sp_executesql  @sql
```